# Create new sheets based on a list

Tags: vba, excel

When I create new sheets based on the below VBA Code, it works as I want, but there is a small problem. The issue is that when creating all the sheets based on the list given in `Column ("A")`, it create one more sheet with the same name of the original one and also show an error in the code in this section

```
ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
```

Any assistant to correct.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim bottomA As Integer
    bottomA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & bottomA)
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Worksheets(c.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Format").Select
            Sheets("Format").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot in your For statement to state which worksheet the range will be on. So that line should be something like this:

For Each c in worksheet(1).Range("A2:A" & bottomA)

Also there other issue in your code, I just made quick re-write..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim bottomA As Integer

    On Error GoTo eh

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    bottomA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & bottomA)
       'Set ws = Nothing
       'On Error Resume Next
       'Set ws = Worksheets(c.Value)
       'On Error GoTo 0
       'If ws Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Format").Select
        Sheets("Format").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
       'End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

eh:
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks, this is what exactly I was looking for. It work also so fast without any unwelcome message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be explicit as much as possible.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo halt ' Do not use OERN, that ignores the error
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim bottomA As Long
    ' explicitly work on the target sheet
    With Sheets("SheetName")
        bottomA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
        ' explicitly define which workbook your working on
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
        For Each c In .Range("A2:A" & bottomA)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(c.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ws Is Nothing Then
                wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
                    After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
            End If
        Next
    End With

forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Number
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

I don't know why you need to turn events On/Off (I don't see it required at least for your example). Nonetheless, I replaced the `On Error Resume Next` with a more flexible error handling routine because what you did is simply ignoring any errors. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) as well to improve how you work with objects and avoid unnecessary use of `Active[object]` and `Select`.

Comment: Thanks my friend for your input but the same issue also occurred when I used your code as well. an error message after creating the required sheets  and when debug, ( ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value) is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: @NabilAmer What is the error message? Cause this same code works at my end.

Comment: the message error is  Run-time error ‘1004’
Application-defined or objet-defined error       and when you press debug, it goes directly to    (ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value) besides it make one more sheet that not within the list

Comment: @NabilAmer Make sure there is no empty cell in your list.